How to detect if STM32 HAL is used
I wrote this function years ago and the plan was to make it work on a lot of different devices.
I haven't used it in stm32cube before. I can remember that it took a long time to search for the right timer tick function and #ifdef to make it work with the Maple library from Roger Clark.
Today I have changed the code to compile with HAL and I haven't tested it yet. It compiles but I guess that I didn't use the proper check with #ifdef __STM32F1xx_HAL_H to see if I am working in the HAL environment. It will only detect the STM32F1.
What would be a better choice to see that HAL is used?
And is there a better choice for an include file, one that doesn't depend on the 'F' version.
// #include <libmaple/systick.h> // STM32 Maple
   #include <stm32f1xx_hal.h>    // STM32 HAL
// #include <sys\timeb.h>        // WINDOWS ms
// #include <windows.h>          // WINDOWS us
// #include <sys/sysctl.h>       // OSX
// #include <fstream>            // LINUX
// #include <time.h>             // LINUX FreeBSD
// #include <chrono>             // LINUX FreeBSD OSX
   #include "Elapsed.h"
//######################################################################################################
uint32_t elapsed_ms( void ) {
    static uint32_t previous;
    #undef _WIN32
    #undef _WIN64
    #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
        struct timeb now; // #include <sys\timeb.h>
        ftime(&now);
        uint32_t ms = (unsigned long) 1000 * now.time + now.millitm;
    #endif
    #if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__MACH__)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< OSX WAS NOT TESTED YET
        // Apple -> #include <sys/sysctl.h>
        std::chrono::milliseconds ms(0u);
        struct timeval now;
        std::size_t len = sizeof(now);
        int mib[2] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME };
        if (sysctl(mib, 2, &now, &len, NULL, 0) == 0) {
            ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(
                static_cast<unsigned long long>(now.tv_sec)*1000ULL +
                static_cast<unsigned long long>(now.tv_usec)/1000ULL
            );
        }
    #endif
    #if defined(__FreeBSD__)  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< FreeBSD WAS NOT TESTED YET
        // FreeBSD -> #include <time.h>
        std::chrono::milliseconds ms(0u);
        struct timespec now;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_UPTIME_PRECISE, &now) == 0) {
            ms = std::chrono::milliseconds(
                static_cast<unsigned long long>(now.tv_sec)*1000ULL +
                static_cast<unsigned long long>(now.tv_nsec)/1000000ULL
            );
        }
    #endif
    #if defined(__unix) || defined(__unix__)
        // Unix -> #include <...>
    #endif
    #if defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__) || defined(__gnu_linux)
        struct timespec now; // #include <time.h>
        clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now );
        uint32_t ms = (unsigned long) 1000 * now.tv_sec + now.tv_nsec / 1000000.0;
    #endif
    #if defined(__AVR__) // no aditional includes needed
        uint32_t ms = millis();
    #endif
    #if defined(_LIBMAPLE_SYSTICK_H_) // STM32
        //  #include <libmaple/systick.h>
        uint32_t ms = systick_uptime();
    #endif
    //#if defined( __STM32F1xx_HAL_H )
    #if defined( STM32_HAL_LEGACY )
        // #include <stm32f1xx_hal.h> 
        uint32_t ms = HAL_GetTick();
    #endif
    uint32_t diff = ms - previous;
    previous = ms;
    return diff;
}


The only better one I could find so far is: stm32_hal_legacy.h with #if defined( STM32_HAL_LEGACY ). That include file is in all the projects I have created so far.

That's not really an electrical engineering question. Maybe better suited for e.g. STM32 forums? You have some kind of chicken and egg problem, you can't know if a header is included based on the include guard, unless you include a header first. Most of your checks check for what the compiler defines for you. But the compiler cannot know if HAL is used when it compiles your .c file. Like same with AVR, it means you are running an AVR compiler, not that millis() function of Arduino is available.

@Justme, I thought it was the right place because the hal-library tag is available here, not on stackoverflow. You are right about the egg paradox but i will always need a correct include statement. It's just about running the function without the need to go over all code lines to see if the correct part is executed. I have already covered that by checking for #if defined( STM32_HAL_LEGACY ). To finish the code I need an include line for the correct F-version for HAL_GetTick(). Worst case I include all from F0 to Fn and uncomment the correct one.

Then the solution is simple. Make your own defines. User sets one define to what user wants. Or uncomments one of multiple defines what user wants. You then include the correct header and enable the correct code. This doesn't answer your original questiom though.

I think HAL_MODULE_ENABLED might be a contender as well. But you need a definition for HAL_GetTick() and that is in the specific header as fas as I can tell. Sounds quite stupid but main.h has the stuff included... That is at least available on projects created with Cube IDE.

@Arsenal Sure but again chicken and egg problem. If you don't have a file called main.h, or project search directories don't include that path when compiling this file, your compilation fails, even if you use the HAL. If your project has a file called main.h, it is a very common file name and still does not mean you have a HAL project with the definition of HAL_MODULE_ENABLED, or a function called HAL_GetTick(), if you don't even use the HAL, and compilation fails again.
